# Build RCP application with platform specific dll files

Tags: maven, tycho, multiplatform

what is best practice for adding platform dependent resources to products which were respectively built by the maven tycho plugin for different platforms. The platform configuration looks like this:

```
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch> 
                    ...
```

All artifacts are built perfectly but I have this problem. In my case, I would like to copy platform specific dll (or such) files into the respective artifact. These files are used by JNI.

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912772/how-to-use-osgi-fragments-to-contribute-platform-dependent-native-code-with-the) help - or is there a problem with Tycho specifically?

Comment: This approach is maybe a solution to me. I will figure out what I have especially to do. I hope that I can answer this question in the next week. Thanks!!